# How to call parameterized Function from Classic ASP Created in C#

Tags: c#, com, asp-classic

I have created a dll in C# (framework 3.5) and i have declared a parameterized function into that dll. I have compiled the dll successfully. After that I have created a Classic ASP page and I want to call the parameterized function from this page that generates the following error.

`Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01C2)
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'GetData'`

I am Attaching the code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SayHello
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class SayHello : IMyStorage
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string GetData([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string Name)
        {
            return "hello " + Name;
        }

        #region IMyStorage Members
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public void GetData(string name, out string helloName)
        {
            helloName = "hello " + name;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("73EB4AF8-BE9C-4b49-B3A4-24F4FF657B26")]
    public interface IMyStorage
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        void GetData([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] String name,
           [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out String helloName);
    }
}
```

Now I am pasting the code of asp

```
Dim obj
Set obj = Server.CreateObject("SayHello.SayHello") 
' Set obj = Server.CreateObject("SayHello.dll") 
' Set obj= obj.Load("SayHello.dll") 
inputStr = "myString" 
GetObj = obj.GetData(inputStr)
SET Obj = NOTHING 
Response.Write (GetObj)
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close.

It looks to me like your call into `object.GetData()` is passing just one parameter.
At the same time, there are two `GetData()` methods on that COMVisible object.

But COM doesn't support overloading: Two methods with the same name and different sets of parameters.

[COM->.NET - can't access overloaded method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031668/com-net-cant-access-overloaded-method)

If you look at the generated COM interface, there will be two methods in it, one named `GetData` that takes one parameter, and one called `GetData_2` that takes two. I never found this documented anywhere; it's just what I observed in cases like yours.

[Overloads in COM interop (CCW) - IDispatch names include suffix (_2, _3, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1277740/48082)

If you want both of those to be accessible, I'd advise that you discriminate among them explicitly by name, rather than relying on the behavior I described.

---

Also: if you keep `COMVisible` on both of those `GetData` methods, you should include both of them into `IMyStorage`.

Comment: "Wrong number of arguments" indicates an overload problem. You may be getting old COM registration information. I'd suggest a full : refresh your guids, fix your code, and retry it all.

Comment: same error...... I have uplaoded the project Plaese see the link: [URL=http://hotfile.com/dl/118308637/f81b7f5/ReformatingSql.rar.html]http://hotfile.com/dl/118308637/f81b7f5/ReformatingSql.rar.html[/URL]

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the first parameter when you call GetData?
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01C2) **Wrong number of arguments** or invalid property assignment: 'GetData'

```
GetObj = obj.GetData(inputStr)  ' where is the string name?
```

maybe the following fixes the issue:

```
Dim sName
GetObj = obj.GetData(sName, inputStr) 
Response.Write (inputStr)
```